# Active Directory integration with linux users and zimbra

Tags: linux, active-directory, email-server, zimbra

I have the following questions about setting an active directory, that already has users and a domain, (i.e. internaldomain.edu) and real domain (i.e mydomain.edu.), and I have seeing many examples of the integration of AD with linux and usually they have a domain like intranet.mydomain.edu.
Should I change "internaldomain.edu" to intranet.mydomain.edu or to mydomain.edu, or I can leave that internaldomain.edu like it is and create another domain.  I am a littlebit confused with these, I know one is the windows domain but I dont know if that affects my email users.

Comment: Do you have an Exchange server installed in the domain? If so, renaming the domain is highly not-recommended. Otherwise, there's articles on Microsoft's website on how to do that. But, why would you need an additional domain for?

Comment: No, I dont have exchange installed, just AD.  My mail is handled over zimbra.  The thing is that I have 2 domains one internaldomain.edu and mydomian.edu, mydomain.edu is my real domain, www.mydomain.edu is my website to the world, and mail.mydomain.edu is my zimbra.  I want the same users in my active directoy to work on my zimbra. I am just confused with them having different domains.

Comment: Well, you should be able to assign whatever SMTP asddress needed for the users. I don't really see the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question it doesnt matter if you have different domains, in the ldap search base you select the domain of the Active Directory to look for your users.  I still have problems with AD and Zimbra, but these answers my question.

Comment: You don't need to change the title to indicate this is resolved.  You only need to mark your answer as accepted.  See: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Precisely - As long as the username (without the email domain) matches the user name in Active Directory, you can redirect the search base in ldap to your Active Directory Domain.  If you don't mind, I would prefer that if my answer was indeed helpful at least click the up arrow for rep - or if it satisfied your needs entirely, mark it as the best solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is really late, its probably worth answering for someone else.

I have 5 domains hosted on my Zimbra server.  Each and everyone of them authenticate back to an AD Server with one domain, abc.internal.

In each domain configuration for the authentication mechanism is as followd:

- Authentication mechanism: External Active Directory
- LDAP bind DN template: %u@abc.internal
- LDAP URL: ldap://dc.abc.internal:3268

The important thing is, your email user name has to be the same as the user name on the Active Directory server - the template appends abc.internal to that user name.  So joe.schmoe@abc.com actually authenticates as joe.schmoe@abc.internal.

We had several users that didn't have email logins that were the same as their Active Directory login.  I just added their Active Directory login as the email address and aliased their old address to it.  The can login with either the user name or the alias name (which redirects to the user name) without a problem.